# In Apache Hive, what is the difference between "ESCAPED BY" and "FIELDS TERMINATED BY"?

Tags: hive

In Apache Hive, please can you explain to me what is the difference between commands "ESCAPED BY" and "FIELDS TERMINATED BY"? I have tried to look at the documentation online, which is limited and not explained well at all.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When CREATE TABLE in hive, there are two parameters commonly used:"FIELDS TERMINATED BY" and "ESCAPED BY". "FIELDS TERMINATED BY" is used to Separate columns，However,"ESCAPED BY" apply to single column for values.
For example,there is a row data

```
C0,   C1,   C2,   C3, C4, C5
123, "456, code", "", "", 236
```

when you create table,you want separate columns by ',', But you also want to keep "456,code" as a whole,

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    C0 int, 
    C1 string, 
    C2 string, 
    C3 string, 
    C4 string, 
    C5 int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY ","; 

when you select * from test,you may get "456,code" other than "456", "code"
```